# Scene showing black outlines with no object faces

Tags: 3d-view

I just downloaded a .blend file from blendswap but when i opened it in blender it is looking like graphs, i mean it looks like a bare structure, no white faces (walls). please help.[image]

Comment: it might be helpful in getting better answers if, in addition to the screenshot, you could post a link to the file you downloaded from Blendswap.

Answer (score 1):

At the first sight it looks like you have Viewport shading at wireframe enabled. But I can see it is is at solid. So it should render the faces.

I suggest to check Properties/Object/Display. Maximum Draw Type should be at Textured.

You can also switch to edit mode an see if there are faces (they should become visible when you select the surrounding faces).

Overall it might be a compatibility issue. Do you know what Blender version this file was save with? I think Blender is shows a warning when you open an old blend file. This warning should contain the version.

Be aware that blend data is not necessarily 100% compatible between blender versions. Subsequent versions usually convert fine but long jumps can cause such issues.

If so download that version and load the file there. If that is as you expect you need to find an Blender version that correctly loads the file, save it there and try the same thing until you reach your current Blender version.